# Add diferents animated widgets with diferents layers at the same map

Tags: widget, animatedmarker

I'm making a map with 4 layers that we want to represent them as animated maps.
I think Carto doesn't let to have two animated widgets in the same map.
Does anybody know if it is possible to make two or more animated widgets?